# Convert ARGV to a string so that I can search for text

Tags: ruby

How can I take user input `ARGV.first` and convert it into a string so that I can search for particular text?

I have tried to create a `checkifinstring = #{ARGV.first}.join("")`

The `checkifinstring =~ /s/

Comment: Give example input and output.

Comment: Providing code that does not work does not help. You need to show the expected input and output.

Comment: `ARGV.first` is already a string if you provide a parameter when calling the script. Not sure what you mean by "convert it into a string". And it is a single string. Not sure what you mean by "search for particular text".

Answer (score 1):

If you've read anything about [ARGV](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/ARGF.html#method-i-argv) you've found out it's an array of strings.

Because it's an array, you can walk it, extract individual elements from it, or join the elements to make one long string.

Try writing some code, and execute it from the command-line with some extra parameters. Plug-in lines like:

```
puts ARGV.first
puts ARGV.last
puts ARGV.join(' ')

ARGV.each_with_index do |arg, i|
  puts "arg ##{ i } ==> #{ arg }"
end
```

The first line will return the first parameter passed to the script, the second will be the last, and the third line will be a reasonable facsimile of the commands passed in. The remaining lines will return each argument passed into the script along with its index number.

I saved that as 'test.rb' and ran it from the command-line:

```
ruby ~/Desktop/test.rb one two three four
```

And got this output:

```
one
four
one two three four
arg #0 ==> one
arg #1 ==> two
arg #2 ==> three
arg #3 ==> four
```

Once you know this stuff the rest is easy:

```
ARGV.first['on'] # => "on"
ARGV.first['an'] # => nil
```

If the above doesn't make sense, then dig into [`String[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and its use of sub-string matches.

If you want to use command-line parameters, I strongly suggest you NOT try to reinvent your own system for passing them in, and, instead, rely on Ruby's [OptionParser](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/optparse/rdoc/OptionParser.html) class. It's much more sophisticated and powerful, and will allow you to give your script a standard command-line interface using flags, optional and required parameters, long and short names, built-in help, and can coerce input values from strings to integers and arrays. The documentation for OptionParser is't great, but we can help you with that.

Comment: Thank you very much...I really was not on the right track!

Comment: @user please vote him up..if you helpful on his answer

Answer (score 0):

[ARGV](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#ARGV) contains the command line arguments used to run ruby with the first value containing the name of the executable.

Returns the ARGV array, which contains the arguments passed to your script, one per element.

For example:

```
    $ ruby argv.rb  file1 file2

   ARGV  #=> ["file1", "file2"]
   ARGV.first #=> "file1"
```

So from your question if you got the array of string you can easily search the input string from that array

```
ARGV.select{|f| f == "file1"}
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: The first element of ARGV in Ruby does not contain the name of the executable. It is the first parameter from the command line. See your own example for proof.